# R - subsetting a data frame in a for loop

Tags: r, for-loop, dataframe, subset

im trying to subset a data frame in a for loop to create a smaller data.frame. This is my data.frame

```
day      rain in mm     temperature in °C     season     
1        201            20                    summer
2        156            18                    summer
3        56             -4                    winter
4        98             15                    spring
```

I want to extract a data.frame for each season (with all columns). Here is my code:

```
for (season in seasons){
  a<- weather[which(weather$season %in% season[1]) , ,drop=TRUE]
  ... 
}
```

Unfortunately, the sub-setting doesn' t work. When i use
`a<- weather[which(weather$season %in% "summer") , ,drop=TRUE]` it works perfectly. Also this does not work properly:

```
season <- "summer"
a<- weather[which(weather$season %in% season[1]) , ,drop=TRUE]
```

Does anyone see the problem with my code? Thank you.

Comment: Try `split(weather, weather$season)`. It is better to keep all the data sets in a single list instead of spreading them all over the global environment.

Answer (score 1):

It works with `dplyr`.

```
library(dplyr)
mydf <- data.frame(day = c(1,2,3,4),
                   rain = c(201,156,56,98),
                   temperature = c(20,18,-4,15),
                   season = c("summer", "summer", "winter", "spring"))
seasons <- c("spring", "summer", "autumn", "winter")
for (sea in seasons) {
  a <- dplyr::filter(mydf, season == sea)
  print(a)
}
```